# Unable to logon when connecting to Oracle database with QGIS

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial, connection

I started using QGIS recently and wanted to connect it with our database set on a standalone server. the database installed is (screenshot below).

[image: Oracle database version]

Windows ODBC and lister are well configured, the database works perfectly with other tools and Python, you can see below a screenshot from SQL Developper.

[image: Database in SQL Developper]

I entered the database parameter in QGIS but it won't connect.

[image: QGIS oracle database configuration]

[image: QGIS oracle database connection error]

Comment: What if you put your credential in the 'Basic' tab and from their try to test the connection? Do you receive any kind of ORA-error?

Comment: It's the same error I still get even with 'Basic' credential mode

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue when I updated QGIS to 3.20.
Don't know for what reason, but now when you create a connection to an Oracle DB, you need to specify a value for "Database". If you leave it empty and test the connection, it works but the Ok button becomes grayed out.
In my workaround, I just fill in a random word in the Database field, then go to
C:\Users\<YOUR_USER>\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\QGIS\QGIS3.ini, search for the word I used and delete it.
The line should look like:

```
connections\<YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME>\database=
```

Save the ini file and restart your QGIS and the connection should work.

Hope this helps